# Understanding INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When we implement INotifyPropertyChanged, what is it notifying?

Is it only notifying the View (I doubt it), or every property that has the name (That could provide unwanted affects). Or is it only the properties that exist in the DataContext (doubtful as there is possibly no DataContext in a Model)?

Would it be possible to have a single function like

```
public class Demo : BaseViewModel
{
    public void UpdateAll()
    {
        //Update properties which do not exist in this class
        OnPropertyChanged("NameFromClassA");
        OnPropertyChanged("NameFromClassB");
        OnPropertyChanged("AgeInClassA");
        OnPropertyChanged("AgeInClassC");
    }
}
```

I have tried it, but I can't get it to work. There are no binding errors in the Output window, nor any runtime/compiler issues.

Comment: It notifies whoever is listening... which can be no-one

Comment: When you bind a UI element to a property on an object, that's UI element will subscribe to the PropertyChanged event automatically (this is only one example of how it's used). When you raise the event, it triggers the UI to read your property and possibly update the screen. The comment in your example code is incorrect - the idea isn't to update properties in other classes, but to let other *things* (subscribers) know when *your* property has changed to they can react in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`OnPropertyChanged("NameFromClassA")` is typically implemented in the `BaseViewModel Class` and is equivalent to doing :

```
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
      this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameFromClassA"));
```

It tells whoever is listening to the `PropertyChanged` event of your Demo `Class` that a `Property` named "NameFromClassA" has changed value (your example is wrong because there's no such `Property` in your `Class`).

It's required for `DependencyProperties` bound to `Properties` of your VM to update themselves and is rarely used for anything else.

---

**Edit:**

Psoeudo-code of what's *roughly* equivalent to what the binding engine does behind the scene :

```
ClassA myClassA;
string myPropertyBoundToNameOfClassA;

// somewhere after myClassA was initialized
myClassA.PropertyChanged += OnMyClassAPropertyChanged;

void MyClassAPropertyChanged(string name)
{
   if (name == "NameFromClassA")
       myPropertyBoundToNameOfClassA = myClassA.Name;
}
```

Comment: `It tells whoever is listening to the PropertyChanged event of your Demo Class` This was the crucial part and the answer - that it only notifies properties in the same class (or I assume inherited).

Comment: I added some very simplified psoeudo-code of what the binding engine does behind the scene. It's simply subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event of an instance of a `Class` and therefore it knows the event concerns only _this_ instance of this `Class`...

Answer (score 1):

The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

For example, consider a Person object with a property called FirstName. To provide generic property-change notification, the Person type implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raises a PropertyChanged event when FirstName is changed.

For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source, your bound type should either:
Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred).
Provide a change event for each property of the bound type.

For a Sample Program check this : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)