# Progress Bar C# not showing the real progress

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am new to programming in C#.The program should convert kg tolbs/oz/grams. The kilogram number is in the textBox1 and in the second textBox is the result.The ProgressBar maximum is 50001 and   if i have , for exampe , 400 , it will show me the progressBar complete, even if it should be around 20%-30%. Thank you.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        progressBar1.Maximum = 50001;
        if (s > 0 && s <= 500)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(s * 2.20462262);
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k);
                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Increment(i);
                }
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(s * 35.2739619);
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k);
                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Increment(i);
                }
            }

            if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(s * 1000);
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k);
                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Increment(i);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = "";
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for some of the calls to `Convert` class: use `k.ToString()` and  `k=s*1000`. You're adding an unnecessary layer of indirection and (IMO) it's harder to read. In the first case `Convert` just calls `ToString` and in the second `int * int` is already an `int`. For the `int * double` case though, `Convert` will round to the nearest integer which is probably desired (over explicit cast and truncate). You'd also be safer using `int.TryParse` for the first usage (to prevent crashes on entering letters, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you're using `progressBar.increment` instead of setting the `value` property. `Increment` adds the given value to the current value.

so for example in this loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
{
  progressBar1.Increment(i);
}
```

For the first iteration (i = 1), the value of the progressbar will be 1, for the second iteration it will be 3 because you're incrementing 1 by 2 which equals to 3. For the 3 iteration it will be 6 ...

So instead of using a loop, you could just wirte

`progressBar1.value = k`

Comment: Thank you very much. Love you <3 :*

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell without more context, but my guess is that you never reset the `progressBar1.Value` back to `0` outside of the various `if` blocks. I'm assuming this is part of a winforms or wpf application, you need to notify the main gui thread that a control needs to be updated. The way to do this is typically via `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309677/understanding-inotifypropertychanged) for some background.